# How to log out from both server side and client side on a SSR Nuxt.js application using Firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

As the title suggests, in my Nuxt webapp using **Firebase auth** in **SSR** mode, I want to have the following behaviour :

- As a client, by clicking on logout button from my profile space, I want to keep this state even if I reload the page.

But for the moment it seems to be that I'm only log-out from the **client side** (by clearing cookies, vuex store) but on **server side** User data/session looks still alive, then on page refresh with F5 the vuex store is set-up again, even if we add 'gates' to prevent it ! (check cookies from req object, get local user from res object).

I think something is missing in my config, so can someone tell me what is it ?

=> Here the `nuxt.config.js` file :

```
// ...
firebase: {
    config: {
      apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: `${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.firebaseapp.com`,
      databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: `${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
      appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    },
    services: {
      auth:
      {
        ssr: true
      },
      firestore: true
    }
  },

// ...

pwa: {
    manifest: {
      // ...
    },
    workbox: {
      importScripts: ['firebase-auth-sw.js'],
      dev: process.env.ENV === 'development', // Must be FALSE for prod env.
    },
  },

// ...
```

=> The `index.js` store :

```
import { vuexfireMutations } from 'vuexfire';
import cookieparser from 'cookieparser';

export const mutations = {
  // Plugin used for Firestore operations (read, write) 
  ...vuexfireMutations,
};

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }, { req, res }) {
    if (process.server && process.static) return;
    if (!req?.headers?.cookie) return;

    const { token: currToken } = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie);

    if (!currToken) return;
    if (!res?.locals?.user) return;

    const { allClaims: claims, idToken: token, ...authUser } = res.locals.user

    console.info('Auth User verified on server-side. User: ', authUser, 'Claims:', claims)

    dispatch('onAuthStateChanged', { authUser, claims, token })
  },

  onAuthStateChanged({ commit }, { authUser, claims, token }) {
    console.log('authUser :', authUser);

    if (!authUser) {
      commit('user/resetState');
      return;
    }

    // Set existing user into vuex store
    const existingUser = {
      uid: authUser.uid,
      email: authUser.email,
      token: token,
    }

    commit('user/setUser', existingUser);
  },
};
```

=> The log-out method from `store/user.js` :

```
async logOut({ commit }) {
    try {
      await this.$fire.auth.signOut();

      commit('resetState');
      this.$cookies.removeAll()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error on logout process from client side :', error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

To be more precise, on page refresh, the user data is set again without calling the `commit('user/setUser', existingUser);` line ! Don't know how and why...

Thanks in advance for any help ! :)